# Conditional formatting to rows without a special character *

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, special-characters

How to apply conditional formatting to rows that do not have a special character * or any special characters?

Comment: Please refer to this support article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the * you're after, you can create a new rule *not containing specific text*. [image]

If you need **any** special character (interestingly enough, this doesn't work with *, you'll need to do this in addition to the first one), you can get more complex and add a new column with a formula like this: `=IFERROR(NOT(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890")))),TRUE)`

Then apply a similar conditional formatting rule.

---

I adapted this from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855647/check-if-cell-contains-non-alpha-characters-in-excel).

Let's break it down:

- here we're finding how many alphanumeric characters are in the string: `SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"))`
- `ISNUMBER` surrounds that, and will return a boolean true or false if it's a number
- surrounding that, we're negating the previous boolean with a `NOT`
- the above will throw an error if there's a character that's not in the long list. to address that, we throw `ISERROR` around that to return a TRUE if there's a non alphanumeric character in the target string